# What nodes are created in the DOM tree by this HTML?

Tags: html, dom

In HTML5 what nodes are created in the DOM tree by the following HTML?

```
<div>foo</div>
```

Something like the following?

```
div node
|
|___text-node
```

Comment: Will that show all of the nodes, or a simplified representation?

Comment: There will be div element node and it's content node

Comment: And what is the nature of the content node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is going to be a div `element` and a `textNode` inside (containing foo). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2ygLz44p/1/

Comment: I think it does not. The DOM stays the same but only the browser repaints the page.